# Hanbury-Brown-Twiss single photon autocorrelation experiments

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, experimental-physics

I am looking at setting up an 
[Hanbury-Brown-Twiss (HBT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect) autocorrelation experiment to detect single photons of light in the wavelength range of 600 nm to 1600 nm. I will need two [APD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_photodiode)s / [SNSPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_nanowire_single-photon_detector)s, a time-to-analog-converter / single-channel-analyzer module, and some time tagging electronics. I was wondering if there is any particular equipment that I should consider, or conversely anything I should avoid. Additionally, is there anything else I should look at getting as part of the setup? This will be an extension to an already set-up photoluminescence experiment.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am voting to close because the question is full of acronyms and not clear for a general reader. I had to look for     HBT to get an inkling of what the OP is talking about ,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect

Comment: Instead of time-to-analog converters, you can directly feed the single-photon detector pulses into a time tagger, for example the ones from [PicoQuant](https://www.picoquant.com/products/category/tcspc-and-time-tagging-modules). I've been using the PicoHarp 300 and was very happy with it.

Comment: Do you already know how to implement the code to do the autocorrelation analysis?